# How $\sum_{p-1}^{2p-1} |c_N|=(1+k)^p$ holds?

Tags: proof-explanation, irrational-numbers

Inside the proof of irrationality of $e^k$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ [the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387214445) assumes the following without any details/proof:

> If $f(z)=z^{p-1}(z-k)^p = \sum_{p-1}^{2p-1} c_N z^N$ then $\sum_{p-1}^{2p-1} |c_N|=(1+k)^p$.

I got $\sum_{p-1}^{2p-1} |c_N| \ge (1+k)^p$ not the equality, by $z=-1$. How $\sum_{p-1}^{2p-1} |c_N|=(1+k)^p$ holds, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the binomial theorem, 
$$z^{p-1}(z-k)^p=\sum_{j=1}^p \binom{p}{j}(-1)^j k^j z^{2p-j-1}.$$ Therefore, also by the binomial theorem, 
$$\sum |c_N|=\sum \binom{p}{j}|k|^j=(1+|k|)^p.$$

Since $k\in\mathbb N$, $|k|=k$, and the desired equality follows.

Comment: So how $\sum_{p-1}^{2p-1} |c_N|=(1+k)^p$ holds?! Please note about absolute value inside the sum.

Comment: I'm aware, which is why the $(-1)^j$ disappeared.  If you don't understand the proof, then you should think about it more carefully, and perhaps write out some calculations or examples yourself.

Comment: Believe me, I tried *many* times : it's $|\sum_{p-1}^{2p-1} c_N|$ that equals $(1+k)^p$ not when absolute value is inside! The proof of irrationality of e is much more lengthy and complicated but I finished it except for this equality inside it. Could you explain more how absolutes $|c_N|$ appear? Thanks

Comment: No, that is incorrect.  The sum with absolute values on the outside is $|(1-k)|^p$.  Maybe try things with $p=3, k=2$ to see what's going on?